# How to pass data from one recycler view item to next item in same recycler view?

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-room

I am practicing on room database in a small calculation app. I want when I update data in one item in recycler view, the next items update automatically. In my app, when I update credit or debit closing balance changes. Now the changing closing balance set to the next item as the opening balance, and continue the process.

Custom Adapter:

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Balance> dataset;
Context context;

//************************My ViewHolder Start*********************************

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_opening_balance;
    TextView tv_total_deposit;
    TextView tv_withdrawal;
    TextView tv_closing_balance;
    Button btn_title;
    LinearLayout ll_card_balance;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.tv_opening_balance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_opening_balance);
        this.tv_total_deposit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_total_deposit);
        this.tv_withdrawal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_withdrawal);
        this.tv_closing_balance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_closing_balance);
        this.btn_title = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_title);
        this.ll_card_balance = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_card_balance);
    }
}
//************************My ViewHolder End*********************************


public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Balance> dataset, Context context) {
    this.dataset = dataset;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_balance, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    TextView tv_opening_balance = holder.tv_opening_balance;
    TextView tv_total_deposit = holder.tv_total_deposit;
    TextView tv_withdrawal = holder.tv_withdrawal;
    TextView tv_closing_balance = holder.tv_closing_balance;
    Button btn_title = holder.btn_title;
    LinearLayout ll_card_balance = holder.ll_card_balance;

    tv_opening_balance.setText(dataset.get(position).opening_balance + "");
    tv_total_deposit.setText(dataset.get(position).credit + "");
    tv_withdrawal.setText(dataset.get(position).debit + "");
    tv_closing_balance.setText(dataset.get(position).closing_balance + "");
    btn_title.setText(dataset.get(position).financial_year+"");


    //***********************Random color logic********************************
    Random random = new Random();
    int red = random.nextInt(255);
    int green = random.nextInt(255);
    int blue = random.nextInt(255);
    btn_title.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));

    //*******************************
    /*int i=0;
    for ( i= 0 ; i<=dataset.size();i++){

        tv_opening_balance.setText();
    }*/


    ll_card_balance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int financial_year = dataset.get(position).financial_year;
            Double opening_balance = dataset.get(position).opening_balance;
            Double credit = dataset.get(position).credit;
            Double debit = dataset.get(position).debit;
            Double closing_balance = dataset.get(position).closing_balance;

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);


            intent.putExtra("financial_year", financial_year);
            intent.putExtra("opening_balance", opening_balance);
            intent.putExtra("credit", credit);
            intent.putExtra("debit", debit);
            intent.putExtra("closing_balance", closing_balance);


            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataset.size();


}
```

}

Repository
public class BalanceRepository {

```
private String DB_NAME = "balance_db";

private BalanceDatabase balanceDatabase;
Context context;

public BalanceRepository(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    balanceDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, BalanceDatabase.class, DB_NAME).build();
```

//        Toast.makeText(context, "Database is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

```
//******************Insert Task Start************************

public void InsertTask(final Balance balance){
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            balanceDatabase.balanceDao().insertTask(balance);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Toast.makeText(context,"F.Y.:"+balance.financial_year+" is saved " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

//******************Insert Task End************************

```
//***************Get data Task Start************************

public List<Balance> getBalance()
{
    List<Balance> balanceList = balanceDatabase.balanceDao().getAll();
    return balanceList ;
}

//***************Get data Task End************************

//***********************Update Task Method start**********************

public void UpdateTask(final Balance balance)
{

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            balanceDatabase.balanceDao().updateTask(balance);

            return null;

        }
    }.execute();
}

//***********************Delete Task Method end**********************


//***********************Update Task Method start**********************

public void deleteTask(final Balance balance)
{

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            balanceDatabase.balanceDao().deleteTask(balance);

            return null;

        }
    }.execute();
}

//**********************Delete Task Method end**********************
```

Update Activity
public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btn_delete, btn_update;

```
EditText edt_year, edt_ob, edt_credit, edt_debit;
TextView tv_cb;

int sfinancial_year;
double sopening_balance, scredit, sdebit, sclosing_balance;

String sfinancial_year_to_update = "", sopening_balance_to_update = "", scredit_to_update = "", sdebit_to_update = "", sclosing_balance_to_update = "";

String sfinancial_year_to_delete = "", sopening_balance_to_delete = "", scredit_to_delete = "", sdebit_to_delete = "", sclosing_balance_to_delete = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

    btn_delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    btn_update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_update);

    edt_year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_year);
    edt_ob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_ob);
    edt_credit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_credit);
    edt_debit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_debit);

    tv_cb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_cb);



    Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (data != null) {
        sfinancial_year = data.getInt("financial_year");
        sopening_balance = data.getDouble("opening_balance");
        scredit = data.getDouble("credit");
        sdebit = data.getDouble("debit");
        sclosing_balance = data.getDouble("closing_balance");

        edt_year.setText(sfinancial_year + "");
        edt_ob.setText(sopening_balance + "");
        edt_credit.setText(scredit + "");
        edt_debit.setText(sdebit + "");
        tv_cb.setText(sclosing_balance + "");


        btn_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    tv_cb.setText(closing_balance());

                    if (edt_ob.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                            || edt_credit.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                            || edt_debit.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                            || tv_cb.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill detail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        sfinancial_year_to_update = edt_year.getText().toString().trim();
                        sopening_balance_to_update = edt_ob.getText().toString().trim();
                        scredit_to_update = edt_credit.getText().toString().trim();
                        sdebit_to_update = edt_debit.getText().toString().trim();
                        sclosing_balance_to_update = tv_cb.getText().toString().trim();




                        BalanceRepository balanceRepository = new BalanceRepository(getApplicationContext());

                        Balance balance = new Balance(Integer.parseInt(sfinancial_year_to_update), Double.parseDouble(sopening_balance_to_update), Double.parseDouble(scredit_to_update),
                                Double.parseDouble(sdebit_to_update), Double.parseDouble(sclosing_balance_to_update));
                        balanceRepository.UpdateTask(balance);




                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All data is Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();

                    }

            }
        });

        btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sfinancial_year_to_delete = edt_year.getText().toString().trim();
                sopening_balance_to_delete = edt_ob.getText().toString().trim();
                scredit_to_delete = edt_credit.getText().toString().trim();
                sdebit_to_delete = edt_debit.getText().toString().trim();
                sclosing_balance_to_delete = tv_cb.getText().toString().trim();

                BalanceRepository balanceRepository = new BalanceRepository(getApplicationContext());

                Balance balance_to_delete = new Balance(Integer.parseInt(sfinancial_year_to_delete),Double.parseDouble(sopening_balance_to_delete),Double.parseDouble(scredit_to_delete),
                        Double.parseDouble(sdebit_to_delete),Double.parseDouble(sclosing_balance_to_delete));

                generate_delete_dialog(balance_to_delete);
            }
        });

    }
}

    private String closing_balance () {
        double opening_balance, credit, debit;
        if (edt_ob.getText().toString() != "" && edt_ob.length() > 0) {
            opening_balance = Double.parseDouble(edt_ob.getText().toString());
        } else {
            opening_balance = 0;
        }
        if (edt_credit.getText().toString() != "" && edt_credit.length() > 0) {
            credit = Double.parseDouble(edt_credit.getText().toString());
        } else {
            credit = 0;
        }
        if (edt_debit.getText().toString() != "" && edt_debit.length() > 0) {
            debit = Double.parseDouble(edt_debit.getText().toString());
        } else {
            debit = 0;
        }
        return Double.toString(opening_balance + credit - debit);
    }

//********************* Generate delete alert dialog method start ***************

public void generate_delete_dialog (Balance balance)
{
    final Balance balance_about_to_delete = balance;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UpdateActivity.this,R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle); // don't write getApplication Context

    builder.setTitle("Warning");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure to delete? \n "+"Financial Year : "+balance_about_to_delete.financial_year);
    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //delete code
            BalanceRepository balanceRepository = new BalanceRepository(getApplicationContext());
            balanceRepository.deleteTask(balance_about_to_delete);
            Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this," Data deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog deleteDialog = builder.create();
    deleteDialog.show();
}

//********************* Generate delete alert dialog method end ***************
```

[image: img_balance]

Comment: I want to set the closing balance of 2001 in the opening balance of 2002 and continue.